# Changed imports in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I started creating a new website with angular 9 and angular material. So far this worked:

```
import {MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';
```

now i get an error and have to change it to:

```
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
```

Something changed with the imports in Angular 9 and material? I found nothing in the documentation.

Comment: yup that's how it is supposed to be in angular 9 check here: https://update.angular.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://update.angular.io/) for Angular updates

For angular material you have to do according to the documentation:

Instead of importing from @angular/material, you should import deeply from the specific component. E.g. @angular/material/button.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is a bit more work now and i don't think code will have a better legibility